# Installation of Nxt on Ubuntu

Tags: nxt

I'd like to install Nxt on Ubuntu (a private node). I am a beginner and have no clue about how to do that. Is there anyone out there that could give me some directions/advices ?

Any help would be wonderful.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just download from https://nxt.org/download/ unzip, go to folder and `./run.sh`
Then go to your browser open up nxt by going to `http://127.0.0.1:7876/`

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: You cannot just execute ./run.sh  you need to first do ./compile.sh then you do a ./run.sh